# Having trouble setting the header to point to a new node in a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

So I'm attempting to insert something as the new head of a linked list (I created a function for it and all that) - but for some reason when I run the code I get a segmentation error - I've narrowed down where the cause of the node is, but I'm not sure why it's causing a problem?

**most_freq.h**

```
#ifndef MOST_FREQ_H_
#define MOST_FREQ_H_

#include <stdio.h>

//used to hold each "word" in the list
typedef struct word_node
{
char *word;
unsigned int freq; //frequency of word 
struct word_node *next;
} word_node;

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile);

int ReadLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer);

struct node *GetMostFrequent(struct word_node *head, unsigned int num_to_select);

void PrintStringList(struct word_node *head);

void FreeStringList(struct word_node *head);

void SortedInsert(char * word, word_node *head);

void PushNewHead(node_t ** head, char * word);

struct word_node* CreateNode(char * string);

char *strip_copy(const char *s); //removes any new line characters from strings

#endif
```

**most_freq.c**

```
#include "most_freq.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* str_buffer = NULL;

struct word_node* CreateNode(char * string) {
    word_node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(word_node));
    new_node->word = string;
    new_node->freq = 1;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

void PushNewHead(word_node ** head, char * word) {
    word_node * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(word_node));

    new_node->word = word;
    new_node->next = *head;
    printf("*Head word is: %s\n", (new_node->next)->word);
    *head = new_node;
    return;
}

void SortedInsert(char * word, word_node *head) {
    //first check if head node is empty
    if(head->word == NULL) { //if head->word is null, then list is empty
        //setup head node
        head->word = word;
        head->freq = 1;
        head->next = NULL;
        return;
    }
    else { //otherwise, list isn't empty and we need to traverse it
        word_node * current = head; //set current to head parameter
        word_node * prev = NULL; //set previous to NULL (to track previous node)
        printf("Attempting to insert: %s\n",word);
        while(current != NULL) { //while current isn't null
            char* currentNodeWord = current->word;
            if(strcmp(word,currentNodeWord) == 0) { //word matches current node's word
                printf("%s is already in the list, updating the frequency counter\n",word);
                current->freq++; //increase node's frequency
                break;
            }
            else if(strcmp(word,currentNodeWord) > 0) { //word comes after current node's word alphabetically
                prev = current;
                current = current->next; //move current node pointer
            }
            else if(strcmp(word,currentNodeWord) < 0) { //word comes before current node's word alphabetically
                //prepare node for insertion
                if(current = head) { //if current = head, then we're at the first item in the list
                    printf("%s is the new head node.\n",word);
                    PushNewHead(&head,word);
                }
                struct word_node * new_node = malloc(sizeof(word_node));
                new_node = CreateNode(word);
                prev->next = new_node;
                new_node->next = current;
            }
        }
        //if current node is null, we're at the end of the list, so insert the new node

    }
}

void PrintStringList(struct word_node *head) {
    word_node * current = head;
    printf("List of Strings (and Frequencies)\n\n");
    while(current != NULL) {
        printf("%s (Frequency: %d)\n", current->word, current->freq);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int ReadLine(FILE *infile, char * line_buffer) {
   fscanf(infile, "%s", line_buffer);
   str_buffer = strdup(line_buffer);
   if(str_buffer[0] != '\0' || strcmp(str_buffer, "") != 0) {
    return EXIT_SUCCESS; //return success code
   }
   else {
    return EXIT_FAILURE; //return failure code
   }
}

struct node *readStringList(FILE *infile) {

    //setup empty linked list
    word_node * root = NULL;
    root = malloc(sizeof(word_node));
    if(root == NULL) { //check if root was successfully allocated
        printf("Not enough memory to create linked list.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char* temp_buffer = malloc (sizeof(char) * 255); //buffer for 255 chars
    while(!feof(infile) && ReadLine(infile, temp_buffer) == EXIT_SUCCESS) { //while there is still something to be read from the file
        SortedInsert(str_buffer, root); //pass in root node to str_buffer
    }
    printf("Preparing to print list.\n");
    PrintStringList(root);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2) // no arguments were passed
    {
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); /* "r" = open for reading, the first command is stored in argv[1] */
        if ( file == 0 )
        {
            printf( "Could not open file.\n" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Starting program.\n\n");
            readStringList(file);
        }
    }
    else if (argc < 3) {
        printf("You didn't pass the proper arguments! The necessary arguments are: <number of most frequent words to print> <file to read>\n");
    }
}
```

**text file (read in as an argument when executing from terminal)**

```
bat
bat
bat
ant
```

I think the issue lies in the line `*head = new_node` but I can't figure out exactly why that would be causing a problem?

Comment: Maybe you need to provide complete code. From here your `malloc` maybe failing or `head` may be  uninitilaized.

Comment: Is `*head` null by any chance?

Comment: I'll edit to provide the full thing then, I don't think *head is null as I can read from `(new_node->next)->word` after setting `new_node->next = *head` but maybe there's something I'm forgetting?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @TaiM. Why do you point to `char *` to store string ? Use `strcpy` instead of that after allocating memory to `word`.

Comment: @ameyCU which part of the code are you referring to specifically?

Comment: @TaiM. In some function you do this - `new_node->word = word;` (_This is from function_ `PushNewHead`). I would suggest to use `strcpy` instead.

Comment: @ameyCU doing that seems to have caused another segmentation fault at that line, not sure why though? (as I can call "word" in a print function, and if I revert back to using `new_node->word = word` it works fine though I still have the segmentation error at `*head = new_node`

Comment: @TaiM. Do you allocate memory to `new_node->word` before copying ? If not then you must do that .

Comment: @ameyCU that took care of the strcpy issue, but I'm still getting the segmentation fault on the `*head->node` line - do I need allocate memory for that as well?

Comment: @TaiM. Where excatly is that line ?

Comment: One thing worth considering could be to never change the head node (as in make another node the head) but instead swap it's contents with another (new) node in case the new word comes before the head's word. This could lead to a cleaner design.

Comment: @DanielJour I thought of the same thing, I ended up just doing that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, the problem is the interface to `SortedInsert()`.  You have:

```
void SortedInsert(char *word, word_node *head);
```

This prevents `SortedInsert()` from reporting on a new head.  It cannot change the `head` in the calling code.  There are two possible designs (both of which work):

```
word_node *SortedInsert(char *word, word_node *head);  // V1
void SortedInsert(char *word, word_node **head);       // V2
```

Clearly, they're used differently:

```
head = SortInserted(new_word, head);  // V1
SortInserted(new_word, &head);        // V2
```

Your code also has numerous other issues.  Among the ones I remember fixing:

- You don't detect EOF reliably until after you've tried using the last entry twice.
- You have a weird organization with the `str_buffer` global variable and the `temp_buffer` variable.
- You read words, not lines, in the function `ReadLine()`.
- You use `struct node` in various function prototypes when you probably mean `word_node` (or `struct word_node`).  (Exercise: do you know why the compiler didn't complain?)
- You declared functions that are not implemented (so your code isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verfiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).
- Your testing code didn't print the list each time an element is added.  This is something that is a common mistake.  You need a printing function; you need to exercise that function on empty lists, and one element lists, and two element lists, etc.  You can spot trouble much more quickly that way.  (An early version of the code added `bat` happily, but failed to add `cat`, but was successful adding `ant`, but not anything else.  It was easy to spot when the list was printed after each entry was added.)
- You had multiple places where you created word nodes, rather than consistently using a single function.
- (Unfixed) You don't have a clearly defined external interface to the package.  All sorts of internal administrative functions (`PushNewHead()`, `CreateNode()`) are exposed as global functions when they should be static.  And you don't separate the `main()` and test code from the 'production' code.
- Memory leaked due to not freeing `str_buffer` when incrementing the count for an existing word instead of adding a word.

Here is some code that resolves most of the issues above, and probably fixes a number of other issues.  It stored in a single file (`ll19.c`), but the header could be separated easily.  This version uses the 'V2' interface.

```
#ifndef MOST_FREQ_H_
#define MOST_FREQ_H_

#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct word_node
{
    char *word;
    unsigned int freq;
    struct word_node *next;
} word_node;

word_node *readStringList(FILE *infile);
char *ReadWord(FILE *infile);
void PrintStringList(struct word_node *head);
void FreeStringList(struct word_node *head);
void SortedInsert(char *word, word_node **head);
void PushNewHead(word_node **head, char *word);
word_node *CreateNode(char *string);

#endif

#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct word_node *CreateNode(char *string)
{
    word_node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(word_node));
    new_node->word = string;
    new_node->freq = 1;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    return new_node;
}

void PushNewHead(word_node **head, char *word)
{
    word_node *new_node = CreateNode(word);
    new_node->next = *head;
    printf("*Head word is: %s\n", (new_node->next)->word);
    *head = new_node;
}

void SortedInsert(char *word, word_node **head)
{
    assert(head != 0);
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
        printf("New head word: [%s]\n", word);
        *head = CreateNode(word);
    }
    else
    {
        word_node *current = *head;
        word_node *prev = NULL;
        printf("Attempting to insert: %s\n", word);
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            char *currentNodeWord = current->word;
            if (strcmp(word, currentNodeWord) == 0)
            {
                printf("%s is already in the list, updating the frequency counter\n", word);
                current->freq++;
                free(word);
                return;
            }
            else if (strcmp(word, currentNodeWord) > 0)
            {
                printf("[%s] comes after [%s]\n", word, currentNodeWord);
                prev = current;
                current = current->next;
            }
            else 
            {
                assert(strcmp(word, currentNodeWord) < 0);
                if (current == *head)
                {
                    printf("[%s] is the new head node.\n", word);
                    PushNewHead(head, word);
                    return;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        printf("Regular word: [%s] after [%s]\n", word, prev->word);
        struct word_node *new_node = CreateNode(word);
        prev->next = new_node;
        new_node->next = current;
    }
}

void PrintStringList(struct word_node *head)
{
    word_node *current = head;
    printf("List of Strings (and Frequencies):\n");
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s (Frequency: %d)\n", current->word, current->freq);
        current = current->next;
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

char *ReadWord(FILE *infile)
{
    char line_buffer[255];
    if (fscanf(infile, "%254s", line_buffer) == 1)
    {
        char *str_buffer = strdup(line_buffer);
        if (str_buffer != 0 && strcmp(str_buffer, "") != 0)
            return str_buffer;
        free(str_buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}

struct word_node *readStringList(FILE *infile)
{
    word_node *root = NULL;
    char *str_buffer;

    while ((str_buffer = ReadWord(infile)) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Line: [%s]\n", str_buffer);
        SortedInsert(str_buffer, &root);
        PrintStringList(root);
    }
    return root;
}

void FreeStringList(word_node *node)
{
    while (node != NULL)
    {
        free(node->word);
        word_node *next = node->next;
        free(node);
        node = next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s file\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: could not open file %s for reading.\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("Starting program - reading %s.\n", argv[1]);
    word_node *root = readStringList(file);
    printf("Read complete.\n");
    PrintStringList(root);
    FreeStringList(root);
    fclose(file);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Example file `data.1`:

```
bat
bat
bat
ant
```

Output from running on `data.1`:

```
Starting program - reading data.
Line: [bat]
New head word: [bat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 1)

Line: [bat]
Attempting to insert: bat
bat is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 2)

Line: [bat]
Attempting to insert: bat
bat is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 3)

Line: [ant]
Attempting to insert: ant
[ant] is the new head node.
*Head word is: bat
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)

Read complete.
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
```

Example file `data.2`:

```
bat
bat
cat
bat
auk
dog
ant
bee
ant
cow
bat
pig
hen
```

Output from running on `data.2`:

```
Starting program - reading data.2.
Line: [bat]
New head word: [bat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 1)

Line: [bat]
Attempting to insert: bat
bat is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 2)

Line: [cat]
Attempting to insert: cat
[cat] comes after [bat]
Regular word: [cat] after [bat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 2)
cat (Frequency: 1)

Line: [bat]
Attempting to insert: bat
bat is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
bat (Frequency: 3)
cat (Frequency: 1)

Line: [auk]
Attempting to insert: auk
[auk] is the new head node.
*Head word is: bat
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
cat (Frequency: 1)

Line: [dog]
Attempting to insert: dog
[dog] comes after [auk]
[dog] comes after [bat]
[dog] comes after [cat]
Regular word: [dog] after [cat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
cat (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [ant]
Attempting to insert: ant
[ant] is the new head node.
*Head word is: auk
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 1)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
cat (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [bee]
Attempting to insert: bee
[bee] comes after [ant]
[bee] comes after [auk]
[bee] comes after [bat]
Regular word: [bee] after [bat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 1)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [ant]
Attempting to insert: ant
ant is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [cow]
Attempting to insert: cow
[cow] comes after [ant]
[cow] comes after [auk]
[cow] comes after [bat]
[cow] comes after [bee]
[cow] comes after [cat]
Regular word: [cow] after [cat]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 3)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
cow (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [bat]
Attempting to insert: bat
[bat] comes after [ant]
[bat] comes after [auk]
bat is already in the list, updating the frequency counter
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 4)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
cow (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)

Line: [pig]
Attempting to insert: pig
[pig] comes after [ant]
[pig] comes after [auk]
[pig] comes after [bat]
[pig] comes after [bee]
[pig] comes after [cat]
[pig] comes after [cow]
[pig] comes after [dog]
Regular word: [pig] after [dog]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 4)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
cow (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)
pig (Frequency: 1)

Line: [hen]
Attempting to insert: hen
[hen] comes after [ant]
[hen] comes after [auk]
[hen] comes after [bat]
[hen] comes after [bee]
[hen] comes after [cat]
[hen] comes after [cow]
[hen] comes after [dog]
Regular word: [hen] after [dog]
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 4)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
cow (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)
hen (Frequency: 1)
pig (Frequency: 1)

Read complete.
List of Strings (and Frequencies):
ant (Frequency: 2)
auk (Frequency: 1)
bat (Frequency: 4)
bee (Frequency: 1)
cat (Frequency: 1)
cow (Frequency: 1)
dog (Frequency: 1)
hen (Frequency: 1)
pig (Frequency: 1)
```

Is the code perfect now?  No, far from it.  But it has been run under [`valgrind`](http://www.valgrind.org/) and has a clean bill of health — no memory leaks from this code with the two test files shown.  (I'm not going to claim that no other test file could find a leak, but I'm modestly optimistic.)